# How do I get the body of the POST request with WCF?

Tags: json, .net, wcf, post, request

I want to get the body of the POST request in json format with WCF, below is my code:

Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetBody", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void GetBody(Stream stream);
```

Client(uses restsharp)

```
var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("/GetBody", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"PortalType\":\"Merchant\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
```

I get the following error: "StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 2897)"
I tried various methods but never succeeded, can only ask for help！

If the client code is changed to the following, then the body can be successfully obtained.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("/GetBody", Method.POST);
//request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"PortalType\":\"Merchant\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
requst.AddParameter("PortalType", "Merchant");
var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the request parameter of your GetBody is of type Stream, and you set the Content-Type to application/json when sending the request to the WCF service, so the WCF service will report a bad request error.

When we want to send a Stream data, the Content-Type should be **application/octet-stream**, If you do not set the Content-Type, the Content-Type defaults to application/octet-stream when transmitting Stream type data.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the right solution. You need to set the ContentTypeMapper of the web service to force it to use raw to parse the request.